# Editing colour of category tabs in Magento

Tags: magento

Anybody know where to find the css that will edit the colour of the text in the category tabs?

Answer (score 4):

Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, you can inspect the element on the page, and the right-hand side will show the CSS affecting that control, as well as what file that CSS is contained within. This should show you where the color is being set.

As a generic note, all the CSS is usually contained within the `/skin/frontend/default/default/css/` folder. Since some of these files are very long, Firebug is helpful for finding the line number to examine.