# magento - change the colour of the footer links text

Tags: css, magento, hyperlink, footer

hoping somebody might be able to help me.
I am currently using a hellothemes theme.
I would like to change the colour of the footer links text. Any ideas on how to?

Also can anyone explain the differences between the CSS's on Boxes.css:

- Mage_CSS_B Common Elements
- Mage_CSS_E Shop Pages
- Mage_CSS_F Overrides
  etc...

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 1):

This question is similiar to [your other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207510/magento-editing-colour-of-category-tabs/1207558#1207558).

If you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, you can inspect the Footer link text, and see the line of CSS that is deciding the color. It's much easier than trying to guess what each line of CSS is trying to do.